# Trying to play a sound using AVFoundation

Tags: swift, xcode, avfoundation

I am quite new to Xcode therefore apologies if the below requires a simple fix. Have created a simple button as a test for a different project, imported the mp3 file under the "Supporting Files" directory and the below is my code which is giving a number of errors due to tutorials I followed which were all using different versions of Xcode.

AVFoundation was also added to the project.

**Errors:**

> Argument labels '(_:, error:)' do  -- Extra argument 'error' in call
>   Use of unresolved identifier 'alertSound'

**Code:**

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var AudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        let alertSound = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "two", ofType: "mp3")!)
        print(alertSound)

        AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, error: nil)
        AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true, error: nil)

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func n2(_ sender: UIButton) {

        var error:NSError?
        AudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfUrl: alertSound, error: &error)
        AudioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
        AudioPlayer.play()
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a side-note, but you should follow consistent naming rules when naming your variables, i.e. `AudioPlayer` should be `audioPlayer`. 
See https://swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines/

Answer (score 1):

For the first error:
Argument labels '(_:, error:)' do -- Extra argument 'error' in call

Objective C function which contains an error parameter and returns a boolean will be marked as a function which can potentially throw exceptions in Swift 3. You can handle the error using a do..try..catch construct.

You can check Apple Documentation on error handling here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ErrorHandling.html

The other error related to the AudioPlayer variable being a local variable which is being accessed outside of the scope.

```
   var AudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

// Declare alertSound at the instance level for use by other functions.
let alertSound = URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "two", ofType: "mp3")!)

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    print(alertSound)

    do {
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
    }
    catch {
        print("ERROR: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}

@IBAction func n2(_ sender: UIButton) {

    do {
        AudioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: alertSound)
        AudioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
        AudioPlayer.play()
    }
    catch {
         print("ERROR: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}
```